# Magrittr two way pipe and multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm recycling an answer from someone else's question but could someone tell me if the approach below can be used to meet multiple conditions before making the change?

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df[df$tag=="ggyg",] %<>% mutate(tag="xxx")
```

I tried this but it isn't working.

```
 df[df$tag=="ggyg",] %<>%  df[df$h.tank==2,] %<>% mutate(tag="xxx")
```

I'm trying to use the approach above as it would save a lot of time instead of using ifelse statements to meet conditions.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what happens instead of what you want? Are you getting a warning about invalid factor levels, for example?

Comment: Have you tried `df[df$tag=="ggyg" & df$h.tank==2,]`?

Comment: That's great! Seems to be doing exactly what I wanted, meeting multiple conditions and then changing the row to something I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading up conditions into different clauses, why not combine your conditions into one statement?

```
df[df$tag=="ggyg" & df$h.tank==2,] %<>% mutate(tag="xxx")
```

Or a little more idiomatically:

```
df %<>% mutate(tag = ifelse(tag == "ggyg" & h.tank == 2, "xxx", tag))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 pure `magrittr`/`dplyr` solutions:

```
df %<>% inset(tag == "ggyg" & h.tank == 2,"tag","xxx")              # pure magrittr
df %<>% mutate(tag = inset(tag,tag == "ggyg" & h.tank == 2, "xxx"))  # magrittr & dplyr
```

And some reproducible examples:

```
cars2 <- head(cars)
#   speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3     7    4
# 4     7   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10

cars2 %<>% inset(.$dist==4,"speed",value=1000)
cars2 %<>% mutate(speed = inset(speed,dist==22,2000))

#   speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3  1000    4
# 4  2000   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10
```